# TypeScript - How to use a runtime mapping of data instead of an interface?

Tags: typescript

The following is a short code snippet that defines two command handlers for a server:

```
import { plainToClass } from "class-transformer";

enum Command {
  COMMAND_1,
  COMMAND_2,
}

class Command1Data {
  foo1!: string
}

class Command2Data {
  foo2!: number
}

const CommandDataMap = {
  [Command.COMMAND_1]: Command1Data,
  [Command.COMMAND_2]: Command2Data,
}

function command1Function(data: Command1Data) {
  console.log("Server got command 1!", data)
}

function command2Function(data: Command2Data) {
  console.log("Server got command 2!", data)
}

type CommandMap = {
  [Value in Command]: (
    data: CommandDataMap[Value], // Compiler error on this line
  ) => void;
};

const commandMap: CommandMap = {
  [Command.COMMAND_1]: command1Function,
  [Command.COMMAND_2]: command2Function,
}

export function onIncomingData(possibleCommand: string) {
  const command = possibleCommand as unknown as Command;
  const commandFunction = commandMap[command];
  if (commandFunction === undefined) {
    console.error("Invalid command:", command);
    return;
  }

  const dataClass = CommandDataMap[command];
  const validatedData = plainToClass(dataClass, data, {
    strategy: "exposeAll",
  });
  commandFunction(validatedData);
}
```

The idea here is to use the "class-transformer" library from NPM to turn the raw data into a class, and validate it in the process.

The compiler says to change `CommandDataMap` to `typeof CommandDataMap`, but then the compiler complains that the function signatures don't match anymore, so I am very confused.
Can anyone explain what is going on?

I can get the code to compile by changing `const CommandDataMap = {` to `interface CommandDataMap {`. However, this breaks my program, because TypeScript deletes interfaces at runtime, and I need the mapping to exist at runtime so that I can perform validation on incoming data. Another option is to completely copy-paste the entire thing into a runtime version and a non-runtime version, but this is terrible and obviously prone to breaking.

It seems like the compiler should be smart enough to read the type of the object and use that instead of an interface?

Comment: Your `class` types really should be `interface` or `type`. Unless you have a constructor defined you shouldn't use `class` (because a TypeScript `class` compiles to a JavaScript `class`, which is just sugar for a constructor function). The fact you felt you needed to use `!` (e.g. `foo1!: string`) is a code-smell and should warn you that you're _probably doing something the wrong way_. You should never need to use the non-null assertion  `!` operator in TypeScript.

Comment: No, I cannot use interface or type, because those are destroyed at runtime by the TypeScript compiler. As explained above, I need to validate incoming data at runtime. In fact, this is best-practice as demonstrated by popular server-side TypeScript frameworks such as NestJS.

Comment: You need to learn to embrace type-erasure - don't try to make TypeScript work like RTTI languages like C#. "I need to validate incoming data at runtime. In fact, this is best-practice as demonstrated by popular server-side TypeScript frameworks such as NestJS." - I feel the best way to do this is with interfaces and type guard-functions. You cannot use a TypeScript `class` with data deserialized from JSON, for example (as `object` data in JSON can only be interpreted through an interface, not a `class`, as there's no ctor invocation nor prototype chain setup).

Comment: [This code](https://tsplay.dev/W4peBW) makes it compile, but I am not sure what you're doing with those class constructors.  Can you augment your [mre] to show the use case?  Right now they seem unmotivated and [this version with no constructors](https://tsplay.dev/Na0Q6w) would work just as well.  If that version fails to meet your use case, as you're saying, an example showing the failure would be extraordinarily helpful.

Comment: "because TypeScript deletes interfaces at runtime" - this is incorrect: TypeScript does not delete interfaces at runtime. They're erased at compile-time. BTW, this is also exactly how a C compiler works too (except in C it's struct definitions instead of interfaces, and memory ranges with memory offsets instead of JS objects with named properties).

Comment: @Dai The most non-opinionated way for type guard-functions to learn a schema is to feed them a vanilla ES6 class. There are libraries that let you build validation schemas, but these are proprietary and opinionated, and often have to be built separately from the actual data definition itself.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! I'll try out that modification. You are correct in that the MRE does not show the motivation. The real motivation is to use the popular "class-transformer" library from NPM. It has a helper function "plainToClass" that you feed raw data and a class constructor, and out comes an instantiated class with data that is guaranteed to be safe to use. No undefined values, no mismatched types, and so on.

Comment: @James "The most non-opinionated way for type guard-functions to learn a schema is to feed them a vanilla ES6 class": I don't know what you're referring to here - TypeScript's type-guard functions don't have anything to do with ECMAScript classes (ES6 or otherwise), and ES6 has nothing to do with TypeScript's own semantics (it's just an output target). Are you thinking of `instanceof`? What do you mean by "learn a schema"? Type-guard functions should be pure-functions, so there's no "learning" going on...

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer explaining why you need `InstanceType` to convert from `typeof CommandDataMap` to `CommandMap`, but I still feel like I'm missing something about the use case.

Comment: @Dai Sorry, I am probably not being very clear. It is my understanding that type-guard functions are functions that are manually created by programmers in order to narrow down the object type of an incoming variable. However, I don't want to manually create any code. Instead, if I use the popular "class-transformer" library, then I can simply feed it a class constructor, it learns the schema from that, and passes me back sound data.

Comment: @jcalz I will update the question now.

Comment: @James You are correct in that type-guard functions for narrowing (e.g. from `object` or `unknown` to some known type) can be tedious to write by hand, but there's just as many tools for generating type-guards from JSON Schema files as there are for generating constructors - and as I said, constructors won't help you in this case because you're dealing with already-parsed data whereas constructors are only useful for creating new data within your program.

Comment: @jcalz It's updated now; does that give enough information about what the use-case is?

Comment: @Dai The constructor does help; see https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#enforcing-type-safe-instance

Comment: @James That's doing a lot more than just enforcing type-safety at runtime though - it's converting object-literals into instances of defined class types (and more besides). In my opinion that's overkill for most applications and I've never needed to use anything like TypeStack's class-transformer in any of my own projects. YMMV - I just don't see how this adds value to most projects. I have nothing more to add. If it works for you then that's good, I just don't think it's a good idea for most other people and projects.

Comment: @Dai This is a tremendously easy and robust way to sanitize incoming user-data. How do you generally do it? By manually creating if statements to check for all of the particular fields that you need, and then by manually creating if statements to check `typeof` of those fields? Doing that violates DRY and the validation can easily get out of sync with the source interface/schema.

Comment: @James I have my own tooling for generating type-guards from `interface` and `type` syntax, as well as JSON Schema and Swagger files as part of the build process (and for design-time too). Most type-guards are single-line `return` expressions (rather than hand-written `if` statements). That's not a violation of DRY nor does it fall-out-of-sync. I agree that TypeScript _should_ generate type-guards by itself but I understand the TypeScript design team's [reasons for not doing so](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628).

Comment: Swagger is great, but there's more than one way to skin a cat. :) For many it is much easier to use an NPM library than to use tooling to auto-generate scaffolding. And using an NPM library keeps the complexity low.

Comment: "And using an NPM library keeps the complexity low." - given the state of the npm ecosystem I can't repeat that with a straight-face. Incidentally this article is doing the rounds today: https://nadh.in/blog/javascript-ecosystem-software-development-are-a-hot-mess/

Comment: @Dai I read through the GitHub issue you linked; thanks, that was a good read. From there, I found https://www.typescriptneedstypes.com/ , which lists the libraries that people seem to be using to solve this problem.  The highest rated looks to be Joi, with 18k stars. But Joi seems bad because you define the schema with a proprietary Joi constructor. Tied for second is TypeGraphQL and class-validator/class-transformater. The former seems to be solving for a slightly different problem, and the latter is what I've already set out to use in this thread, so it seems like this is a popular choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally I think your problem is that you're not properly distinguishing between *types* and *values* in TypeScript.  TypeScript types exist only in the static type system and are not present at runtime, while JavaScript values do exist at runtime.  Values can be said to *have* types (or *be of* a type, or *inhabit* a type), but they are not types themselves.  In TypeScript some expressions refer to types and others refer to values, and these are determined syntactically from context and not by name.  In the following code:

```
const Foo: Bar = Baz as Qux;
```

`Foo` and `Baz` refer to values, and `Bar` and `Qux` refer to types, purely based on syntax.  A named type can have the same name as a completely unrelated named value; the fact that they have the same name does not imply any relationship between them.  So you could also write:

```
const Bar: Foo = Qux as Baz;
```

and the names `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` and `Qux` could refer to completely different things from the prior statement.   For example:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string;
}
interface Bar {
    b: number;
}
interface Baz extends Foo {
    c: boolean;
}
interface Qux extends Bar {
    d: Date
}
const Baz = { d: new Date() };
const Qux = { c: true };

const Foo: Bar = Baz as Qux;
const Bar: Foo = Qux as Baz;
```

You can see that the type `Baz` is something like `{a: string, c: boolean}` while the value `Baz` is `{d: new Date()}`.  So the type of (the value) `Baz` is not related to (the type) `Baz` at all:

```
const nope: Baz = Baz; // error
// Type '{ d: Date; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Baz': c, a
```

Also note that if you have a named value, you can use [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to get the type of that value in TypeScript:

```
type TypeofBaz = typeof Baz;
// type TypeofBaz = {  d: Date; }
```

and, again, if there's a type named `Baz` and a value named `Baz`, there's nothing saying `typeof Baz` and `Baz` need to be related in any way.

---

Class statements like `class Command1Data { foo1!: string }` bring both a named value and a named type into scope.  The named value is a class constructor, while the named type is the type of instances of the class.  So the type `Command1Data` is essentially the same as `{foo1: string}`, while the type of the value `Command1Data` (a.k.a. `typeof Command1Data`) is essentially the same as `new() => Command1Data`.

This is a common source of confusion about the difference between named values and named types.  There are many situations in which `XXX` is both a value and a type, and where `typeof XXX` is essentially the same as `new () => XXX`, but this only happens to be true in the case where you have a class declaration of the form `class XXX`.  You can't rely on it to be true in general.  It doesn't even make sense when `XXX` is a generic type parameter, since there probably is no value named `XXX` at all.

---

With that all out of the way, let's look at your original definition of `CommandMap`:

```
type CommandMap = {
    [Value in Command]: (
        data: CommandDataMap[Value] // error
    ) => void;
};
```

You need to annotate the `data` function parameter with a type.  The form of `CommandDataMap[Value]` implies that you are [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a type  `CommandDataMap` with a key of type `Value`.

The first problem is that there is no type named `CommandDataMap`.  You have a *value* with that name, but there is no built in relationship between types and values.  If you are trying to consult the `CommandDataMap` value to define `CommandMap`, you will need to use `typeof CommandDataMap` to get its type:

```
type CommandMap = {
    [Value in Command]: (
        data: typeof CommandDataMap[Value] 
    ) => void;
};

const commandMap: CommandMap = {
    [Command.COMMAND_1]: command1Function, // error
    [Command.COMMAND_2]: command2Function, // error
}
```

Now you are referring to a type, but you still have an error.  Let's inspect `CommandMap` to see why:

```
/* type CommandMap = {
  0: (data: typeof Command1Data) => void;
  1: (data: typeof Command2Data) => void;
} */
```

Note that `typeof Command1Data` is the type of the *value* named `Command1Data`, which is a class constructor.  That makes sense; `CommandDataMap` holds class constructors, not instances.  So you have said that `CommandMap`'s property values are callbacks accepting class constructors.  That's apparently not what you want.  You want your callbacks to accept class instances.

So you need to take these constructor types and turn them into the appropriate instance types.  You can do this with [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype):

```
type X = InstanceType<typeof Command1Data>;
// type X = Command1Data
```

(Again, the fact that the class constructor value is named `Command1Data` and the instance type is also named `Command1Data` is not generalizable.  You shouldn't think "`XXX` is the same as `InstanceType<typeof XXX>`"; it's not true and often doesn't make sense.)

So `typeof CommandDataMap[Value]` is a constructor type, and the corresponding instance type is `InstanceType<typeof CommandDataMap[Value]>`:

```
type CommandMap = {
    [Value in Command]: (
        data: InstanceType<typeof CommandDataMap[Value]>
    ) => void;
};
```

And now your `commandMap` definition is accepted:

```
const commandMap: CommandMap = {
    [Command.COMMAND_1]: command1Function,
    [Command.COMMAND_2]: command2Function,
} // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5c0CCwAmA1EANgK7RIDeAUBUjUgJbAAuEATgGYLIBiA9j+dVpCQALiRRGLBgHMA3IJoBfBfSasOiJACEQLAUKEAjMcCJhDreUOVCGzdp20gAXkggAPZjihJe-Sga08GKGfAQQIMBWtDa0duqOAIpE7m6eEN5OegGBSNhiACIgzCqxNPA8wBJOrgC85HkmEADuSEXMABQAlEiK0eWV1cmp9WRIwUiSJL3yKhVVjL58Yjp69TquID7D-eODi6tifkj1w0hbNbNC89XAPDAQKy4nl0gA9G9uLCw8LCofSAAKgBPB5IADkY3ybWKEFkvXB9B8YDoUCgMkmAAtkGweAQCDxmhiYD8HixGHRSGwfmBJqDkOCNuCxPAADTnKhCRj0oH0nhsDYvbkPfmXf6fYXIEEigXPUY0aHtOG9KgUZRUDJmJAAYR4YDAkWw+lo2oA8gBZc0YFAFAD6AEZWSozZbrXaAExO9XwAhbHy6-WG+3tEDGmi4nj2gCEYgkUmA0jVVB9fp1eoNOHdIbDSAj7pjSFM5lYSYoN0WAYz2BD5pAMBeORoAG1K4aAHQuq02h0AXTErZwweKICdQhb6fbnbdtvdfbTgczIa9VDeACo9gt51Wa3WxI2kAAGMSS0UD7BDxggXb2498thbw1Z4fyRRIVdvKhsIjAeAUyp7Bdzy4b9fzoSoOmwYd+wnQcQx6fcbjxCA2wJaQOgAIgAZVYAA3VgkGkHhFgqQCkGjdD2Ugy8ulLL8fz-YAAKrd1gPosDgAgqCH0XYd4LmQYkJQng0Kw3D8MI4iYKNfMKLyXjSwoUBIFgRwUHuZB90lbjsFretRhUMd8GIZAGG0ucOgM3IqNEOkZW0ncYCbIySB7SyaB6WoAD4kBwng6GwXY+k5Wg1xULSz10htLKPJBOMvW87LPC8QA87zfP83YaBvWLrISiBTykp9qJONK-IC0okBUd9goGTcSKrXToMAyL9NyJBx0AjsLS7O17Tneqg1Y0DKlHXIOqrLrXW7WcWUKoaGNGpQFK0gANF4AEkFkiRBpQgAAeE97ySkNPPkAFVpeY7hyocKpJanMnMIaZTLPcy3Lk+KkE2iRtogXaDrvezh10x7jJ7TyVFSnyypfWZyyYw1Gu0+793GyduunPrZsA+15vYxb2rPSaepnfq5pAha1SAA)